# Как на практике реализовать Singleton через enum от Joshua Bloch’а?

Tags: java, singleton

Есть относительно известная реализация шаблона Singleton от Joshua Bloch’а которая часто иллюстрируется вот в таком виде:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Я решил реализовать ее в реальном коде и столкнулся с некоторым непониманием. Вот общая картина: Есть DAO слой который и должен воплощать упомянутый выше шаблон:

```
public class TaskDAO implements DAO<Integer, Task> {

    private final AtomicReference<SessionFactory> factory;

    public TaskDAO(final AtomicReference<SessionFactory> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    ... CRUD методы ...
}
```

Вопрос в том как мне использовать `enum` если я хочу при создании инстанса использовать динамическую инъекцию зависимостей?

Сомневаюсь что Joshua Bloch этого не учел...

Или сам паттерн исключает использование конструктора? (Хотя странно если его главная задача гарантировать что экземпляр будет только один, то не понятно как внедрение зависимостей через конструктор может противоречить этой идее... Или противоречит?).

Если подитожить все выше сказанное в виде вопроса на который который можно дать конкретный ответ: Идея шаблона синглтон противоречит внедрению зависимостей через конструктор, или только версия Joshua Bloch'a?

Comment: Никогда не используйте синглтон. Это антипаттерн независимо от конкретной реализации. И DI с ним не совместим.

Comment: @Victor Khovanskiy в доках Hibernate написано что пул конектов к базу должен быть синглтон. Нет возможности писать свой ORM "объектно ориентированный"

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy остаётся понять, как антипаттерн попал в книгу про паттерны, да ещё и продолжает по сей день появляться во всех учебниках. Даже у Google в официальной документации по Android есть рекомендации к его использованию.

Comment: @Pavel, вы путаете обычный синглтон из любого языка программирования (который в вопросе) и синглтон как прокси объект из DI. Во втором случае пул потоков ведет (и только ведет) себя как синглтон, то есть хранит в едином контексте ваши коннекты, но по факту передаваться могут разные объекты.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, во-первых, в книгах всякое пишут, но обычно при их чтении используют голову или хотя бы стараются её использовать. Во-вторых, это тиражируемая ошибка. В-третьих, SDK у android - одна сплошная ошибка и гугл это признали. Но обратную совместимость им нужно поддерживать. Кстати, пример их рекомендации приведите, если возможно.

Comment: @Victor Khovanskiy то есть правильно ли я вас понял что документация hibernate не имеет в виду синглтон буквально а просто говорит что фабрика подключений должна быть одна? Но даже если так все равно логично сделать "защиту от дурака" написав так что-бы второй экземпляр создать было просто не возможно..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сама концепция *Singleton* противоречит принципу *Dependency Injection*.

Проблема с *Singleton*  состоит в том, что они представляют собой глобальное состояние, которое трудно предсказать, особенно в тестах.

Имейте в виду, что объект может быть по факту *Singleton*, но доступ к нему все равно можно получить через *Dependency Injection*.

В свое время тоже озадачивался таким вопросом, и сохранил себе в Evernotes [статью](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/05/03/singleton-vs-dependency-injection/), принципы из которой использую уже больше года =) Вот перевод:

> Важно поддерживать баланс между зависимостями, представленными как
>   синглтоны и те, которые вводятся с использованием принципов *Dependency Injection*.
>   Надеюсь следующие подсказки помогут вам определить, какой шаблон
>   использовать:
>
> - Если зависимость является "глобальной", то есть она используется многими классами и / или несколькими слоями, используйте *Singleton*.
> - В противном случае добавьте его в зависимые классы, используя шаблон *Dependency Injection*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]